# Sent2Vec or Doc2Vec Testing

Tags: doc2vec

How can i test a sent2vec or doc2vec model that I've trained on a specific dataset?  The process is all unsupervised so have no labels to help in the testing. My interest is in how the semantic similarity measure is computed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your goals? Which dataset(s)?

Comment: Thanks @gojomo for the response. Dataset comprises of tweets related to an event. The goal is in relation to semantic similarity between other tweets, or a held out test set on the same dataset based on the trained model.  I have no labelled set and have no manpower to do that.  A quick look at the relevance in related tweets that I get in one of the algorithms is quite promising at least by human evaluation. How can I quantitatively evaluate the performance of the models. I have already trained them.

Comment: That's still not quite clear, but you'll need *some* hint of which tweets should be considered more-similar than others to do any kind of scoring. You could hand-build this, or perhaps use something else in the tweets (like a shared hashtag) as a hint that certain pairs should be closer to each other than to a randomly-chosen third tweet. (See section 3.3. of the original 'Paragraph Vectors' paper for an example of using this sort of scoring: https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4053 )